# Use constructor inheritance to provide conversion between sibling types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor

I want to allow the following behaviour:

```
struct SignalBase {};

struct Signal1 : public SignalBase
{ using SignalBase::SignalBase; };

struct Signal2 : public SignalBase
{ using SignalBase::SignalBase; };

int main()
{ 
    Signal1 s1;
    Signal2 s2(s1);
}
```

Of course, that doesn't work since `SignalBase` has no constructors receiving derived types, and copy constructors are not inherited with the `using` clause.

I've tried to solve this problem with a template constructor inside SignalBase:

```
// External function:
template<typename Derived, typename Base>
constexpr bool isDerived()
{
   return std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>::value and
      !std::is_same<Base, Derived>::value;
}

struct SignalBase
{
   template<typename Signal>
   SignalBase(Signal const& s)  // (1)
   { static_assert(isDerived<Signal, SignalBase>(), "Invalid copying"); }
};
```

Since the constructor (1) cannot be confused with a copy constructor (if I'm not wrong, template constructor are not considered copy constructors, since non-template copy constructor has priority over template constructors if they has the same signature as a copy constructor after instantiated).

So, constructor (1) should be inherited in derived class:

```
// struct Signal1 inherits:
template<typename Signal>
Signal1(Signal const& s)  // (2)
{ static_assert(isDerived<Signal, SignalBase>(), "Invalid copying"); }

// struct Signal2 inherits:
template<typename Signal>
Signal2(Signal const& s)  // (3)
{ static_assert(isDerived<Signal, SignalBase>(), "Invalid copying"); }
```

And a line like:

```
Signal2 s2(s1);
```

should instantiate (3) with `Signal` = `Signal1`, which is a derivate class of Signal and causes no errors due to the `static_assert` clause.

But this doesn't happen since the compilation error says that no conversion is found from `Signal1` to `Signal2`.

Why isn't the base constructor properly inherited, and what is really being inherited in derived classes?

**NOTE**: In my real code (not shown in this example for simplicity), the derived signals are templates, and casting operators only works for explicit castings (using the `(Type)object` operator), which makes lines too long in places where I'm sending objects between functions. That's why I want to search a way to do it by means of constructors.

**NOTE 2**: Please, focus on the C++ issue problem (which is really being inherited?) and not on other OOP considerations (e.g, does it make sense construct derived objects from base clases?), since this is a very reduced example of my real code.

Comment: `Signal1`  and `Signal2` have `SignalBase`  as their lowest common ancestor. Thus when doing `Signal2 s2(s1)` , it makes no sense to keep anything but the `SignalBase`  part of `s1` when doing that. A cast to `SignalBase` should do

Comment: What do you expect `Signal2 s2(s1)` to do, exactly? In a clear OOP class hierarchy, `Signal2` does by definition not know anything about `Signal1`. How is its constructor supposed to create a useful instance given an argument of something it is not supposed to handle? It's like constructing a `Dog` from a `Cat` because both are `Animal`s. I wonder if inheritance is the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Christian Hackl The key thing is that the derived classes has not own data members. I create them only to disambiguate other templates and function templates, but in some places I want to reuse functions which works perfectly fine with different signals.

Comment: @Rerito See my note at the end of the post.

Comment: Why do you need a template?  Please describe the specific problems you have with using a constructor taking `const SignalBase&` instead.  Oh I see, you're trying to make something work with `using`.

Comment: I am not sure what you tried. Take a look at working code: http://ideone.com/RAxxId.

Comment: @Peregring-lk: I'm still not sure I understand why a simple `Signal2(Signal1 const &)` would not suffice. You apparently only want to allow this for certain classes. It is a special case. Having to be explicit about this and allowing the compiler to catch accidental wrong uses, utilising simple basic C++ without any template magic, now that's something I would consider an *advantage*...

Comment: @Ben Voigt Your idea implies to write a `SignalBase const&` constructor for each derived class.

Comment: @Peregring-lk: Only for those where you want to allow this special construction.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Ok that's right. If I don't find a solution, I have no choice but make what you say, but I want to know why my original approach doesn't work. Which constructors are really being inherited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done without templates by adding a second layer of base classes:

```
class SignalBase
{
    /* all the members */
};

struct CopyableSignalBase : SignalBase
{
    // not actually a copy constructor, so using will pick it up
    CopyableSignalBase(const SignalBase& src) : SignalBase(src) {}

    // make all other (not copy and not default) constructors available too
    using SignalBase::SignalBase;

    // since using doesn't introduce default constructor, provide it
    // if and only if SignalBase had one
    CopyableSignalBase() = default;
};

struct Signal1 : public CopyableSignalBase
{ using CopyableSignalBase::CopyableSignalBase; };

struct Signal2 : public CopyableSignalBase
{ using CopyableSignalBase::CopyableSignalBase; };
```

Note that Visual Studio cannot handle inheriting constructors at all until VS14, according to [this feature matrix](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/11/c-11-14-feature-tables-for-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx).  But the whole question is meaningless without constructor inheritance.

Comment: This does not compile if you actually try `Signal1 s1; Signal2 s2(s1);`.

Comment: (even if you add a default constructor for `Signal1`)

Comment: @ChristianHackl, you need other default constructors too, then it will compile.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I don't know what the parameters should be for constructing an object from scratch.  Adding a trivial default constructor to `CopyableSignalBase` works for me: http://rextester.com/KTPVR25461

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I must be missing something very obvious. It doesn't compile even if I add public default constructors to all classes.

Comment: Seems like VC 2013 refuses to compile this even with default constructors added everywhere. `error C2664: 'Signal2::Signal2(const Signal2 &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'Signal1' to 'const Signal2 & - Reason: cannot convert from 'Signal1' to 'const Signal2' - No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called`. GCC does not complain.

Comment: @BenVoigt: This SSSCE fails in VC 2013. Bad, bad VC!

Comment: And I did compile with `/Za`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I think VC++ hasn't implemented constructor inheritance, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/08/21/c-11-14-features-in-visual-studio-14-ctp3.aspx.  `CopyableSignalBase s2 = s1;` works while `Signal2 s2 = s1;` does not.   Should be ok in next release.

Comment: @Peregring-lk: Yes, we've already determined that g++ and clang++ compile this, while VC++ 2013 doesn't due to incomplete C++11 support.

Comment: @BenVoigt: You're right. Fortunately, it seems that support comes with VC 2015, at least according to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx